# Initialize a column with missing values and copy+transform another column of a dataframe into the initialized column

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data

I have a messy column in a `csv` file (column A of the dataframe).

```
using CSV, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = ["1", "3", "-", "4", missing, "9"], B = ["M", "F", "R", "G", "Z", "D"])
```

Want I want to do is:

1. Transform the integer from string to numeric (e.g. `Float64`)
2. Transform the string `"-"` in `missing`

The strategy would be to first define a new column vector filled with missing

```
df[:C] = fill(missing, size(df)[1])
```

and then perform the 2 transformations with for loops

```
for i in 1:size(df)[1]
    if df[:A][i] == "-"
        continue
    else
        df[:C][i] = parse(Float64,df[:A][i])
    end
end
```

However, when looking at `df[:C]` I have a column filled only with missing. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, but first let me show how I would write this transformation:

```
df.C = passmissing(parse).(Float64, replace(df.A, "-"=>missing))
```

It is not the most efficient way to do it but is simple to reason about.

An implementation using a loop could look like:

```
df.C = similar(df.A, Union{Float64, Missing});

for (i, a) in enumerate(df.A)
    if !ismissing(a) && a != "-"
        df.C[i] = parse(Float64, a)
    else
        df.C[i] = missing
    end
end
```

Note that `similar` by default will fill the `df.C` with `missing` so the `else` part could be dropped, but this behavior is not documented so it is safer to write it.

You could also use a comprehension:

```
df. C = [ismissing(a) || a == "-" ? missing : parse(Float64, a) for a in df.A]
```

Now, to fix your code you could write:

```
# note a different initialization
# in your code df.C allowed only values of Missing type and disallows of Float64 type
df.C = Vector{Union{Float64, Missing}}(missing, size(df, 1))

for i in 1:size(df)[1]
    # note that we need to handle missing value and "=" separately
    if ismissing(df.A[i]) || df.A[i] == "-"
        continue
    else
        df.C[i] = parse(Float64,df.A[i])
    end
end
```

Finally note that it is preferred to write `df.C` than `df[:C]` to access a column in a data frame (currently both are equivalent but this might change in the future).

Comment: In your proposed fix, shouldn't you check column A instead of C for missing or "-" elements? I think this was the bug in the question as well.

Comment: Thank you, fixed. I was aware of this bug, but these are the risks of copy-pasting :). Actually this is the reason I preferred the first solution as it uses transformation-based approach.